# Difference of getHandShakeStatus() in SSLEngine and SSLEngineResults in java

Tags: java, handshake, sslengine

I am trying to create a Client/Server connection with SSLEngine in java. I would like to ask what is the difference between `SSLEngine.getHandshakeStatus()` and `SSLEngineResults.getHandshakeStatus().` I have found a sample code of Nuno Santos about `SSLEngine` and multiplexing with NIO API.

**The code I refer to is:**

```
                    //some code here
                    SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus hs = engine.getHandshakeStatus();
                    String clientString = "";

                    while (hs != SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus.FINISHED && hs != SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus.NOT_HANDSHAKING)
                    {
                        switch (hs)
                        {
                        case NEED_UNWRAP:
                            if (socketChannel.read(peerNetData)< 0)
                            {
                                engine.closeInbound();
                            }
                            peerNetData.flip();
                            SSLEngineResult res = engine.unwrap(peerNetData, peerAppData);
                            peerNetData.compact();
                            hs = res.getHandshakeStatus();
                            switch (res.getStatus())
                            {
                            case OK:
                            //TODO something
                                break;
                            case BUFFER_UNDERFLOW:
                        //TODO something
                                break;
                            case BUFFER_OVERFLOW:
                            //TODO something
                                break;
                            case CLOSED:
                            //TODO something
                                engine.closeInbound();
                                break;
                            }
                            break;
                            //more code here
```

**The link with the code I've found is:**
http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/11/03/ssl-nio.html?page=last&x-order=date

The sample code is in Resources section

Thanks in advance!

Comment: They should be the same, though I doubt you'll ever need `SSLEngine.getHandshakeStatus()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They aren't the same. The status returned as `SSLEngineResult.getHandshakeStatus()` by calling `wrap()` or `unwrap()` can include FINISHED, but you will never get that from the status stored in the `SSLEngine.` The reason is that it's a transient status.

NB poor quality code. There's not much point in trying an unwrap or anything else after you've just read end of stream.